# Обработка html тегов при выводе из MySQL

Tags: теги, html, php, mysql

Есть форма, которая добавляет запись в бд, но при выводе из бд `html` теги не обрабатываются, то есть текст получается таким:

```
<h1>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</h1>
```

Как включить обработку тегов?

Comment: А каким он должен быть на выводе?

Comment: На выходе он должен быть обработанный тегом h1, а сейчас теги выводятся простым текстом

Comment: А что, сами теги разве не простой текст? Пойду пацанам расскажу.

Comment: Нужно, что бы при выводе из бд, текст, например, заключённый в тег b становился жирным, а сейчас выводится на странице просто <pre><b>текст</b></pre>

Comment: Ну тогда PHP-код в студию.

Comment: echo "<h1>".$row['text']."</h1>"; Сделай что-то в этом роде

Comment: Делаю через fat free фреймворк:
    
     $db = new DB\SQL('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=articles', 'root', 'root');
     $article=$user=new DB\SQL\Mapper($db,'article'); 
        F3::set('html_title','Редактирование записи');
        $url = F3::get('PARAMS["url"]');
        $article->load("url='$url'");
        F3::set('html_title',$article->url);
        $article->copyTo('POST');
        F3::set('content','admin_edit.html');
        F3::set('title','admin_edit.html');
        if (!F3::get('SESSION.user')) F3::reroute('/login');
        echo Template::instance()->render('admin.htm')

Comment: не работает, попробуйте вывести таким способом тег iframe и будет косяк - ошибка 404

Comment: Код наверное лучше засунуть в какой-нибудь pastebin сервис. Тут из кода получается каша.

Comment: Смотрите что в каком виде данные лежат в mysql, воспользуйтесь любым «ручным» mysql клиентом (от штатного консольного /usr/bin/mysql до phpmyadmin), смотрите в каком виде содержимое БД попадает в код страницы (не как оно выглядит, а что там в коде)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При выводе обрабатывай выводимое функцией: **htmlspecialchars_decode**.
Видимо твой фреймворк автоматически преобразует html символы при добавлении.

Comment: Спасибо, работает